# error when building office addin with commandline

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2012, msbuild, ms-office, office-addins

project builds just fine in visual studio 2012 (V11) but does not build when building it with msbuild.exe through the command line

error received:

> error MSB4062: The "InitializeDefaultProperties" task could not be
>   loaded from the assembly Microsoft.VisualStudiols.Office.BuildTasks,
>   Version=10.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a.
>   Could not load file 'Microsoft.VisualStudio.Tools.Office.BuildTasks,
>   Version=10.0.0.0

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Turns out the project is a outlook 2010 addin.
The version of **Microsoft.VisualStudiols.Office.BuildTasks.dll** I have in my gac is **v11** instead of **v10** that it seems to require (by default).

Why visual studio CAN build the project probably has something to do with the following line in the csproj file:

```
<Import Project="$(VSToolsPath)\OfficeTools\Microsoft.VisualStudio.Tools.Office.targets" Condition="'$(VSToolsPath)' != ''" />
```

(I don't know where it gets the `vstoolspath` variable from)

I solved this by using an extra build config item `/p:VisualStudioVersion=11.0` used like so:

```
C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\MSBuild.exe
/p:Configuration=Debug /p:VisualStudioVersion=11.0
"$base_dir\OutlookAddin\OutlookAddin.csproj"
```

Comment: `VSToolsPath` is generated based on `VisualStudioVersion`. See this link for details on how this works http://sedodream.com/PermaLink,guid,a5894bad-f2a1-441a-a5b2-74f16c6cf8aa.aspx

Answer (score 0):

I followed these steps.

1.)

> install VS 2010 Tools for Office Runtime
>
> https://www.microsoft.com/en-GB/download/details.aspx?id=48217

2.)

> [image]